# Passing Form ID variable to echo function within javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am unable to pass the `form id` variable to `javascript`
where the date `input = mm/dd/yyyy` with selection of `dropdown` text `A` and text `B` should populate the `JS` output

```js
 $('#Option').change(function(){
   if ($(this).val()== 'A') {
    $('#text1').val('3');
     $('#text2').val("<?php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($myDate . ' +1 Weekdays')); ?>");
  } else if ($(this).val()== 'B') {
     $('#text1').val('8');
       $('#text2').val("<?php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($myDate . ' +8 Weekdays')); ?>");
                           
      }
                        
  });
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-3">
 <label class="control-label" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">Date</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="Date" name="Date" />
 </div>


<div class="col-xs-3">
   <label class="control-label">Option</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="Option" name="Option">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="A" >A</option>
          <option value="B" >B</option>
       </select>
</div>


<div class="col-xs-3">
   <label class="control-label">Text1</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="Text1" name="Text1" />
 </div>

<div class="col-xs-3">
 <label class="control-label">Text2</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="Text2" name="Text2" />
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hufuso0d/3/

Comment: You have typo in js code. lds are `Text1` and `Text2`.

Answer (score 0):

The ids are `Text1` and `Text2`. Try as below :

```
<script>
$('#Option1').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val()== 'A') {
        $('#Text1').val('3');
        $('#Text2').val("<?php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($myDate . ' +1 Weekdays')); ?>");
    } else if ($(this).val()== 'B') {
         $('#Text1').val('8');
         $('#Text2').val("<?php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($myDate . ' +8 Weekdays')); ?>");

        }

    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works!
Pay attention to the correct id: you should insert

```
$('#Text1').val('3');
```

instead of

```
$('#text1').val('3');
```

Comment: agree!! with typo error but not working the Input date not passing to $mydate, even tried $Date ie..$('#Text2').val("<?php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($Date . ' +1 Weekdays')); ?>");

Comment: Keep in mind that `<?php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($myDate . ' +1 Weekdays')); ?>` put a static value in javascript code.
You can't use php code to alter a client side value

Comment: I'm not sure if exists a js function that adds working days to a date. You can also use [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) or [sugarjs](http://sugarjs.com) libraries to add days to a certain date.
Which are the cases that you need to manage in select-field? If you must manage only 1 or 8 working days, you may do it with a simple loop.